# LDA bigrams and trigrams

Tags: python, lda

While making bigrams and trigrams, the code is somehow being executed in a way that the each letter is being considered instead of each word. Please let me know who to fix this! (items is the name of the file)

```py
bigram_phrases = gensim.models.Phrases(items, min_count=5, threshold=50)
trigram_phrases = gensim.models.Phrases(bigram_phrases[items], threshold=50)

bigram= gensim.models.phrases.Phraser(bigram_phrases)
trigram= gensim.models.phrases.Phraser(trigram_phrases)

def make_bigrams(texts):
    return ([bigram[doc] for doc in texts])                       

def make_trigram(texts):
    return ([trigram[bigram[doc]] for doc in texts])

data_bigrams = make_bigrams(items)
data_bigrams_trigrams = make_trigram(data_bigrams)

print(data_bigrams_trigrams)
```

The Output was being displayed like

```
[['m','o','t','i','v',',','O','r','n','a' and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your `items` variable contains an iterable of strings not an iterable of lists of strings which is what the [gensim.models.phrases.Phrases](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/phrases.html#gensim.models.phrases.Phrases) class expects as the argument passed to its `sentence` parameter.

For example, your `items` variable might look like this:

```py
items = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence', 'this', 'one', 'is', 'different']
```

when it should look like:

```py
items = [['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence'], ['this', 'one', 'is', 'different']]
```

Comment: Yes. The variable contains descriptions of different paintings. ['clothes','war', 'bishop', 'angel' , 'coat of arms' and so on. It looks like the first list you wrote. How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to group the words somehow (see my second example). The `Phrases` class is designed to parse multiple groups of words, not just a list of individual words. You need to group the words logically depending on your goal. If you want to just treat everything in items as one big sentence, for example, you can change it to something like: `[['clothes','war', 'bishop', 'angel' , 'coat of arms', ...]]`. I would really recommend re-reading the `Phrases` documentation though so you understand how to use the algorithm to solve your problem.